# Open Twitter from iOS App Not Working Correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twitter

I have been using the following code to open Twitter inside my app. While it works, I can't seem to embed spaces in the NSString.

```
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"twitter://post?message=hello+world"];
NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=hello%20world"];

NSURL *twitterURL = [NSURL URLWithString:string1];
NSURL *mobileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:string2];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:twitterURL])
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:twitterURL];
else
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mobileURL]];
```

Both parts of the code work in the intended situations, but how can I embed spaces in the NSURL? The second piece of code prints "hello2orld" instead of "hello world". I also tried the + delimiter to no avail.

Comment: Using `+` or `%20` are the two ways to encode spaces.

Comment: you should try this stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert spaces to %20 with this instruction:

```
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"twitter://post?message=hello world"];
string1 = [string1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Also you can remove this encoding using other NSString method:

```
– stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding
```